# Solr - Proximity search using exact number of words apart

Tags: solr, solrj

I am working with apache-solr-3.6.0 on windows machine. I would like to search for two words with certain number of words apart (No more than this number).
For example:
Consider the following phrases, I would like to search for Daisy & exam with no more than 2 words apart.

```
Daisy has exam.
Daisy has an exam.
Daisy has a math exam.
Daisy has a difficult math exam.
```

I searched for such thing and I tried Term Proximity.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q="Daisy exam"~2&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on&debugQuery=true
```

The result that I need should be the phrase: `Daisy has an exam.` But using the above criteria, the result was the last 3 phrase.

So any ideas to use an exact number of words apart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the related question here:
[Solr proximity ordered vs unordered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079388/solr-proximity-ordered-vs-unordered)

When you say 'no more than 2 words apart', then you should have both first and second phrase matched. Then your query would be `"Daisy exam"~1`, which will match Daisy exam and an insertion between them (which is **one** change: changes `exam` position from 2 to 3).

In order to prevent "Daisy exam" from the matched result, you can add `-"Daisy exam"` to your query. Alternatively you may add `fq=-"Daisy exam"` to your query string params.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I would like the result to be the phrase: `Daisy has an exam.` and using `~1` wont achieve that result. even using `~2` will not let me have the exact result as if there is a phrase: `Daisy exam.` it will be included, and this is not what I want. Any Ideas?

Comment: I don't think this would be possible with Solr, since `q~x` matches documents with changes less than or equal to x. BTW, you may exclude directly "Daisy exam" in `fq` if it solves the case.